# Where can I find objbase.h for qextserialenumerator in Linux-gnu/C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4, qextserialport

I have downloaded the qextserialport library and used it in my eclipse project. Once I compiled the project I got this error. (gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5))

```
qextserialenumerator.cpp:9: fatal error: objbase.h: No such file or directory
```

I looked for it to include it but I couldn't find it.

What am I missing?

Comment: objbase.h is a windows file, so probably you need to define something so that qextserialport knows it's on linux

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded a recent package? See http://groups.google.com/group/qextserialport/browse_thread/thread/4ccdfecc596fb602 , objbase.h should only be included when building on windows.

Comment: Where can I find the latest one, i mean there is too many clones on the group? plz help

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need it. It is included by the file `qextserialenumerator_win.cpp`.

Comment: you mean I need to delete the files related to windows?

Comment: @newbieLinuxCpp - you should take the newest qextserialport source from http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/source/checkout instead of changing the old one